# Why is Writers StackExchange much more useful than Worldbuilding?

Tags: discussion

Well, Writers StackExchange offers us better/more flexible options for developing our worlds and characters. Is it the fault of badge rushers? To be honest, Worldbuilding expects too much, but offers too little. I don't want to sound like this... However, Writers SE helped me much more than WB.

Comment: They have different topics. Maybe the questions you are asking are a better fit for their site, it doesn't mean we are not helpful.

Comment: @Vincent aside from badge rushers?

Comment: You could easily improve this question *a lot* by citing a few specific examples, ideally on both sites. As it is, beyond the obvious such as that the sites have different topics (which JDługosz has already discussed), what kind of answer do you hope to get to this? This reads like a rant, not a question.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about "badge rushers" . I don't see how it could be a problem anyway. Care to develop?

Comment: Regrettably, there is a thin line between "questions about my world" and "questions about my story."  We answer the first, not the second.  It is very focused, and yet more than 10,000 questions have been asked and answered.  Frankly, I have a lot of fun here, despite the occasional "we don't like that question" and "we don't like that answer" that I receive.  If life were perfect, it'd be boring.

Answer (score 12):

My experience was the opposite. They won’t run with creative ideas, they just say “sure, write something.”  They claim to be about the writing process, not the ideas in a particular story.

If those topics are what you need, than what’s the problem?  You could just as well ask why Writers is better than Cooks: the answer is the same. That is the SE that handles **your** actual questions.